# How do I fix my container so It doesn't continue after I have finished?

Tags: html, css

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8khU.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JzLU.png) I am having a problem with my container on one of my sections on my website. The problem is after I have finished with the content it continues and leaves a massive empty space on my website and not sure what would be the best fix for this. 
I have attempted to make a separate container for the page but the empty space then went to the bottom of the website underneath the footer. The last thing I tried to do was change the maximum and minimum size of the container but that broke other pages.

HTML

```
<section id="section_music" class="section-padding">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="container mb-4">
```

CSS

```
.container {
    align-content: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.kamikaze{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: -500px;
}

.revival{ 
    position: relative;
    top: -230px;
    left: -270px;
}

.tmmlp2{ 
    position: relative;
    top: -460px;
    left: -40px;
}

.recovery{ 
    position: relative;
    top: -690px;
    left: 190px;
}


.relapse{ 
    position: relative;
    top: -920px;
    left: 420px;
}

.encore{ 
    position: relative;
    top: -920px;
    left: -500px;
}

.tems{ 
    position: relative;
    top: -1150px;
    left: -270px;
}

.elp1{ 
    position: relative;
    top: -1380px;
    left: -40px;
}

.tsslp{ 
    position: relative;
    top: -1610px;
    left: 190px;
}

.infinite{ 
    position: relative;
    top: -1840px;
    left: 420px;
```

Comment: please send complete html and css or url where it is running.

Comment: can you show screenshots of the page and post whole html+css+js or just share an online url which we can see?

Comment: Yeah sorry I'm new to coding and stack overflow I don't have an URL yet as I'm doing this for my uni work. However I can send some screenshots.

Comment: I have added 3 screenshots of what I am talking about hope this helps you :)